# Repetition of Time and Yugas in Hinduism

Tags: yuga, kali-yuga, time

The following is the time span of yugas. Now we are in kaliyuga.

[image]

Will these yugas repeat?

If the same yugas repeat, then what about the incidents happening in the universe? Will they also repeat? E.g., I'm typing this question now; will it occur again in the next kaliyuga or a different yuga? Will new incidents also happen?

If yugas do not repeat, then what will happen after kaliyuga?

Comment: what would be the point of creation if the same events repeat themselves over and over again! it is like playing the same video game in the same way every day ! :) But then how many possible combinations can there possibly be, when you do it over eternity? :) Good question +1 !

Comment: If I understand correctly [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7589/3155) answer suggests that they will repeat again.

Comment: @Sai, From philosophy of [Eternal Return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return#Indian_religions) (I added some BG verses only in that article), everything does repeat after some duration. This was believed by Einstein as well. Even I asked the question also on the same: [Does “Free Will” really exist, even if universe repeats itself in perfect pattern?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10911/1049). IMO, because everything repeats, all events have to be fixed. That's a great incentive to avoid repenting past, being carefree about future & ability to renounce reactions in present! :-)

Comment: @iammilind Yes and No. From an Advaita perspective, the world is an illusion of the mind. Being an illusion, past and future are only perceived relative to the mind. Thus they neither repeat themselves nor change. They are completely imagined. :)

Comment: @Sai, not only Advaita, but from every persective. In Gita somewhere there are 2 verses which states: "Prakruti is a sea of MAyA (illustration) & is born out of my nature (swabhAva)". The point of "Eternal Return" is that, the same illusion is imagined during Brahman's day (12 million years) and then complete void for the night (12 million years). So that means that the illusion of writing these comments will happen exactly as it is after Brahman's day & night (say after 24 million years)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the duration (Timeline) of the four "Yugas"?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/what-is-the-duration-timeline-of-the-four-yugas)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The four yugas you listed, join to be called as *Mahayuga or Chaturyuga*. Every cycle(*Mahayuga*) has different happenings all together, its not clear whether each cycle(*Mahayuga*) will have same incidents. There are some marked incidents which have to happen, like the incarnation of Lord Vishnu, they are sure to happen in every yuga and in the same form, the difference will be circumstances.

For example, *Lord Raam* will come in every *Tretayuga*, the *Ramayana* which we read is of this Mahayuga, but we don't know what had happened in previous Mahayuga.

[Kakabhushundi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/who-was-kakabhsundi), gave a reference by telling he saw *Lord Rama* 11 times on earth and every time different things happened.

> Yoga Vashishtha, the text which states conversations between Vashistha, a rig vedic teacher, and various Gods and Kakbhushubdi, a creature which stands outside of normal time and sees all. It recounts the cyclical nature of time, where Kakabhushundi has seen Ramayan 11 times with different outcomes and seen Mahabharat 16 times with different results, but, after seeing Daksha Yagya twice, he did not either care to see it again or saw no point to seeing any more, as it ended the same way each time.

If we keep away linearity and think about Heisenberg's uncertainity principle we get

> Further conversations talk about the atoms or anu at quantam level and inside each quantam level are different universes. A sorrowful queen is shown that her husband is still alive in one of the quantam or atomic universes and ruling wisely and is given the option to join him there. The idea of Heisenberg's Principle is enunciated when a rishi visits and illustrates a decision tree by showing how several parallel universes, with all possible results of a decision, could occur and uses that illustration to explain why he took the decision he did in this universe.

So after Kaliyug there will be definite Satyug to come.

**Concept of Time.**
According to hinduism, [Time](http://baharna.com/karma/yuga.htm) is like a helix, it moves circularly and in one direction, that means major incidents have to happen, like incarnation of Vishnu (not of Shiva, Shiva incarnation depend on cirumstances), but otherwise nothing will repeat.

[image: Helix Showing Semi-Repeated nature of Time]

**More References :**

1. [Avatar's Repeating](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/do-the-same-avatars-repeat-in-each-chaturyug)

Comment: is the repetition of avatara's over each yuga found somewhere in the scriptures?

Comment: @Sai, I have added a reference I found on net, and yes I have read in scriptures somewhere, whenever I'll find I'll add it here.

Comment: I'm sure many users would be interested to look at that whenever it is updated :). thanks!

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan What do you have to say about this? He is saying Rama was born in this Mahayuga but you believe he was born in some other Treta Yuga of an earlier Mahayuga.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Yeah, I don't think it's right at all.  Rama doesn't come in every Treta Yuga, he only came in the 24th Treta Yuga of the present Manvantara.  (The Padma Purana mentions him coming once in a previous Mahakalpa.). And as far as I know, the notion of Kakabhusundi has no basis in Hindu scripture.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria By the way, you can only ping someone with the "@" sign if they are already in a particular comment thread or they're the author of the post you're commenting in.  I just happened to see your comment by chance, I wasn't notified of it.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria, the only way anything can go infinite is through a cycle, therefore its nature of time and god. About, Ram, Vishnu takes avatar whenever needed, and someplace end of every yuga. So there's somewhere Rama, close to end of tretayuga, and Krishna end of dwapar yuga, and Kalki end of Kaliyuga. Now the whole concept of Rama taking birth in previous yugas, is purely theological but do considers the notion that there been such avatars in past. And without Kakabhusundi, the whole notion of my answer is worthless. Hope i'd helped.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan If anyone wants to notify someone who is not in a particular thread then how will he do so? There must be some way.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Well, if you want to talk to the person you can ping them in chat (assuming they've used chat recently), or you can ping them in a comment thread in which they have either participated or where they are the author of the post being commented on.

Comment: Just for record as @KeshavSrinivasan mentioned this answer is wrong. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21692/what-is-chronological-timeline-in-manvantara-and-mahayuga-of-lord-vishnu-incar

Comment: @sidharthchhabra, the repetition of time and yugas is correctly answered, I believe your speculations are around Ramayana happening 11times and Mahabharat happening 16times, you can ask for valid link but can't discard the whole answer.

Answer (score 6):

According to my understanding the all 4 Yugam will be repeated for 1000 times , that will form 1 kalpa, one day of Brahama will end ,and after 360x100 Kalpa (100 years) that is mahakalpa one Life of brahma will end.

In 1 kalpa that is 4000 yugas or 1000 cycle of 4 yuga, the yugs are repeated, one cycle is known as mahayuga.

We are currently in 28th mahayuga .

Brahma is 51 years old means 49 years are left before his life to end.

Ramayana take place in 24th tretayuga of one kalpa.
Mahabharata take place in 28th dwaparayuga of one kalpa.

For Reference see this answer by Keshav
[Did the Mahabharata and the Ramayana happen in the current Yuga cycle in the current Manvantara?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7175/did-the-mahabharata-and-the-ramayana-happen-in-the-current-yuga-cycle-in-the-cur?rq=1)

Answer (score 2):

The collection of all four yugas is called a Chaturyuga. One day of Lord Brahma consists of 1000 such Chaturyugas. This time is called "Kalpa". During this time 14 Manus come and go. Each Manu is created by Lord Brahma Himself, who assigns the Manu with the task of continuing the process of creation by creating generations of mankind called 'Manvantara'. One Manvantara is approximately 71 Chaturyugas. After the Manvantara, Lord Brahma creates another Manu, to carry on the process of creation and procreation. In this new Manvantara, Lord Vishnu takes on a new form, and a new Indra and new Saptarishis are appointed. The current form of Vishnu is the famous four-armed figure having a discus, a lotus, a conch and a mace in each hand. The current Indra is Purandar. The current Saptarishis are Kashyapa, Atri, Vashista, Vishvamitra, Gautama, Jamadagni and Bharadvaja. Later on I will tabulate the other Saptarishis in all the 14 Manvantaras of this present Day of Brahma or the present Kalpa (1000-Chaturyuga-period).

After 1000 Chaturyugas have passed, Brahma's Day is over, which leads to Brahma's Night. During this time, there is no creation as Lord Brahma takes rest. It continues for the same amount of time as Brahma's Day. After the night is over, Brahma commences a fresh creation. The night of Brahma starts with 'Pralaya' (annihilation) and ends with 'Srishti' (creation/manifestation).

=> The actual duration of a Manvantara is 71*4*1000 years, with some additional years, which sum upto 8,52,000 divine years; or 30,67,20,000 human years.

=> 14 times this number constitues a day of Brahma, as there are 14 Manvantaras in one Brahma's Day.

=> Overall, 4,320,000 years termed as 1 Chaturyuga.

=> 1 day of Brahma constitutes 1000 Chaturyugas (= 4,320,000,000 years).

=> Thus 1 year constitutes 360*4,320,000,000 = 1,555,200,000,000 years. Brahma lives for 100 Brahma years.

=> Hence the lifespan of Brahma is 100 years = 100*1,555,200,000,000 = 155,520,000,000,000 years

> **The following table will clearly link our time-scale to that of Lord Brahma's -**
>
> 365*(1/4) human days = 1 Deva Ahoratra (1 day + 1 night)
>
> 360 Deva Ahoratras = 1 Deva Vatsara
>
> 12,000 Deva Vatsaras = 1 Chaturyuga **
>
> 71 Chaturyugas = 1 Manvantara
>
> 14 Manvantaras = 1 Kalpa
>
> 2 Kalpas = 1 Day of Brahma + 1 Night of Brahma
>
> 360 Days of Brahma = 1 Brahma Varsha
>
> Brahma's life span is 100 Brahma Varshas, as we know.

Comment: What you said is true, but question is whether same events of this Mahayuga will happen in next Mahayuga or not?

Comment: Not necessarily. Events won't repeat, but some may, those are coincidental. If events were repeated, why isn't there Rama in this Treta Yuga, when in the Puranas it is clearly written that Rama appeared in the 24th Chaturyuga's Treta? Events are not predetermined, but the timeline structure is. Thanks!

Comment: @user9072 Isnt the calculation wrong in this?
=> Thus 1 year constitutes 360*4,320,000,000 = 1,555,200,000,000 years. Brahma lives for 100 Brahma years.

You have counted only Days (Kalpas) but ignored Pralayas (same duration as Kalpa). There are 360 Kalpas and 360 Pralayas in Brahma's year. You counted only Kalpa?

Answer (score 0):

I studied about cocept of kalpa concept.but it is more projected for any human one life is one kalpa.because all this concept healing a man to make good awakening for understand entire universe and quantom physics.

Our body is main base to understand about it. actually no meaning to longing time as apart from our mind and body whatever there is time lesser or more.Infact human body is very mesterious itself.

All the scientific time concept and vedic concept if we make base our body and mind over than it is clear that to know all these fact.we are taking very short period life even not bramha life time but surya one year galaxy round than also it will pass near to four yug of human life one year.

But if we go to moon 36 days pass than only here is only one day.if we go to than inner quatasize we became ourself one bhrama on their lifeone circle rotataion.so it is too  vast to analysis about time whether it is or not.human conciousness comes on one tik time obesrbation who should ego has to leave to ionized himself.in this without condition man realize it outo system on vibration of throughout strings to universe.