# Each yuga in all mahayuga is different/same?

Tags: puranas, yuga

Its been questioned many times in this forum  about “why vyasa had to divide vedas in every dwapara yuga.” When I was reading brahmanda purana I have got indirect reference to characteristics of same yuga in different mahayuga.

Perhaps Same yuga in different mahayuga might be slightly different in characteristics

Here are the verses of Chapter 32 of brahmanda purana.

Verse 114-119 quotes that

> Whatever occurs in one set of four Yugas happens in the others also in the same manner and in the same order.In the same manner, differences also are produced in every creation. They are restricted to thirty-five and they are remem­bered as neither less nor more. “

Verse 126-127 quotes that "

> Thus the lord always evolves the classification of castes and stages of life in the former Yugas and arranges the intrinsic features of the Yugas."

Does it implies that , there are 35 different varients for each yuga for different mahayuga ?

Comment: There are multiple questions like this , I hope you have already read them ,,every mahayuga is indeed different from other mahayuga.

 according to my knowledge and question of vyasa compiling them every dwapra ,The vedas knowledge remains same independent of mahayug events and can be passed on through the immortals , that is why it is asked why he needs to translate it everytime :)

Comment: @sysinit, this link might help you out http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/time-and-yugas-in-hinduism/3079#3079

Comment: Thx for posting this, really helps clarify something for me w/ understanding the time cycles described in Hinduism :)