# Turn of events every mahayugam

Tags: yuga, manvantara

Whether in every mahayugam same events reoccur with same avatarams and same souls taking birth , following same karma cycle as was in last mahayugam ?

Comment: Related or Possibly Duplicate -https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/repetition-of-time-and-yugas-in-hinduism/3079#3079

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/each-yuga-in-all-mahayuga-is-different-same

Comment: I do mot understand your question at all? Could you correct the grammar?

Comment: SwiftPushkar thanks

Comment: Wikash where is the error ?!