# Why do we not consider Brahma's night as a kalpa?

Tags: yuga, time, kalpa

Why do we consider only the day of Brahma as a kalpa?

1 kalpa = One day of Brahma

2 kalpa = One day + Night of Brahma

Accordingly, "2 kalpa = One day + Night of Brahma" we are in the 101st Kalpa of Brahma.

Could someone please tell me why we consider only the day kalpa of Brahma?

Comment: Because Kalpa is not a unit of time, it's a specific period.  A day of Brahma is called a Kalpa, and a night of Brahma is called a Pralaya.  They're the same length if time, but creation goes on in one of them and destruction goes on in the other.

Comment: ok means we can not consider pralaya in our calendar..., but when  we want to calculate how many years ago loard rama was born in this calculation we consider pralaya or not ?

Comment: Well, Rama lived in the present Vaivasvata Manvantara, as I discuss in my answer here: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/36 So there's no Pralaya in between.  But yeah, if we want to calculate the time between some event in some previous Kalpa and some event in the present Kalpa, we would need to add the lengths of the Pralayas in between.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Few points to answer your question

1. Day time of brahma is known as the Kalpa which is equal to 1000 mahayug .
2. Night time of brahma is known as Pralaya which is also equal to 1000 mahayug.
3. any way we are not in 51 kalpa or 101 (kalpa+pralaya) of brahma, as he is 51 years old that means (51 x 360 day and night)

Current Date according to WikiPedia article (which says just like you 1 full day = 2kalpa)

> This is the first 'day' of the 51st year.[4] This Brahma's day, Kalpa,
>   is named as ShvetaVaraha Kalpa. Within this Day, six Manvantaras have
>   already elapsed[5] and this is the seventh Manvantara, named as –
>   Vaivasvatha Manvantara (or Sraddhadeva Manvantara). Within the
>   Vaivasvatha Manvantara, 27 Mahayugas[5] (4 Yugas together is a
>   Mahayuga), and the Krita,[6] Treta and Dwapara Yugas of the 28th
>   Mahayuga have elapsed. This Kaliyuga is in the 28th Mahayuga. This
>   Kaliyuga began in the year 3102 BC in the proleptic Julian
>   Calendar.[7] Since 50 years of Brahma have already elapsed, this is
>   the second Parardha, also called as Dvithiya Parardha.

Comment: Frankly if you spend just 1 second in brahma place and come back you will say OMG everything has changed :D

Comment: ok and we are in 360 kalpa of 51 years of Brahma is currently running ,we are in last kalpa of current year of Brahma ?

Comment: see this in your answer :  http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3078/time-and-yugas-in-hinduism?rq=1  .......  You mention According to my understanding the all 4 Yugam will be repeated for 1000 times , that will form 1 kalpa, one day of Brahama will end ,and after 100 Kalpa that is mahakalpa one Life of brahma will end...... means you not mention here 51 years of Brahma,  now I am confuse 51 kalpa or 51 years of Brahma