# What are the different endings of Ramayana and Mahabharata as seen by the sage crow Kakabhushundi?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, yuga, kakbhushundi

I have read that Kakabhushundi was a crow that had seen 11 different endings of Ramayana and 16 of Mahabharata. If this is true, what are the other endings of Ramayana and Mahabharata?

Comment: It might be a duplicate.  An answer is available here (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/16142/3869)

Comment: Sir but didnt find my answer. already I have seen that link before posting my question