# What were the different endings of Ramayana and Mahabharata witnessed by KakaBhusudi?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, time, kakbhushundi

Back Story :- I posted this on a subreddit Hinduism about a month ago. And my question is from a response that I got

**The Story (you should give it a read)**:

*Title* :- I found something fascinating in Ramayan that I didn't knew yet. **Death of Ram mentions time loop.***

---

After death of Sita, Ram was devastated and he knew now it was his time to leave this world , but he also knew that up and until Hanuman is alive Yamraj (god of death and righteousness) cannot come to him as Hanuman will stop him.

So he played a trick once he took out his ring and threw it in a crack on ground and asked Hanuman to get it. When Hanuman got into the crack he got to know that it was a way to nag lok (abode of serpents) where he met Vasuki (king of serpents) and told about his mission. then Vasuki led him towards the mountain of rings.

Hanuman did not even waste a second and rushed to the mountain. He picked up the first ring. He was amused to find the original ring in the very first go. He again picked another ring. To his surprise, even that ring was original. He was now confused. He looked at Vasuki in confusion.

“Don’t worry, child. I will explain it to you. but first let me tell you a story” Vasuki calmly spoke.

“There are four yugas and the world keeps on cycling. In the second quarter or treta yuga Rama takes birth, then one day his ring falls into the land of serpents and a monkey comes to take that ring back, and I will tell him the same story. And until then, Rama dies.

The mountain of rings indicates the number of times this repeated. Each time this cycle repeat, a ring is added to the mountain”

Hanuman realizes that he had stuck in the time loop.

Ram’s death gives us a sense of cyclic pattern of time depicted in hinduism.

**The comment I got was this** :-

> Well time loop is the wrong way to put it. Not incorrect because there is an element of truth to it but wrong way to put it. This demonstrates the cyclic nature of universe. Time and space are an illusion here and part of achieving moksha is to understand, not know but understand this.
>
> Let me give you another mind bending anecdote to explain this. There is a being called kak bishundhi in Vishnu Purana who is the teacher of Garuda the mount of Lord Vishnu. An ardent devotee of Lord Rama, he got a boon from Lord Vishnu to exists beyond Time and Space. Why? Because he wanted to observe Ramayana again and again, so he could have Darshan of Lord Rama and his deeds. He has till now observed 7 different endings to Ramayana and 11 different endings to Mahabharata war.
>
> Theologically Ramayana and Mahabharata are events that not only serve a purpose but also are a must in a progression of idea. We cannot avoid both of them just delay it. It must and will happen. But our conduct among these events is something we can control and we can control how this ends.

This means that the rings there in naaga lok are a small substratum of how Ramayana ended. There are other endings where it didn't happen.

So, What were the different endings witnessed by KakaBhusudi ? I know similar question has been asked previously [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37392/what-are-the-different-endings-of-ramayana-and-mahabharata-as-seen-by-the-sage-c), but it hasn't been answered yet and the comment link mentioned in the question leads to description of KakaBhusundi not the endings.

**Edit :- I have specifically mentioned that neither the question( which was said to be duplicate of my question)  nor the question mentioned in the comment of that question, answer my question. The answer which this question refers to has explained** *who was Kak Bhusundi* **not** *the endings*

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/who-was-kakabhusundi

Comment: @hanugm you can clearly see the "edit" above I had mentioned back on May 7 that I am asking what were the endings not who Kakabhusundi was ?