# Multiple Narakasura's in scriptures

Tags: yuga, naraka

Every Tretha yuga contains Rama and Ravana. Similarly every Dwapara yuga has Krishna.

Is there any mention of multiple Narakasura across different mahayugas?

Comment: This notion is wrong. Every Treta Yuga or every Dwapara yuga doesn't have Rama and Krishna.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/3079/661

Comment: That answer is wrong. Rama incarnated in 24th Tretayuga in this manvantara. Krishna incarnated in 28th treta yuga in this manvantara. There will be no need of Rama and Krishna to incarnate again and again. Even if should happen, incarnations repeat once in Kalpa only and not each chaturyuga.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Ramayana of 22nd Tretayuga is also mentioned in Puranas.

Comment: @hanugm Which Purana mentions that?

Comment: @TheDestroyer The Padma Purana