# What is the purpose of repetition of events of every yuga in every Chaturyuga

Tags: puranas, yuga

Although a similar question is asked [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/do-the-same-avatars-repeat-in-each-chaturyug). I have not found the answer for the question.

What is the purpose of repetition of events of every yuga in every
 Chaturyuga.

Are only important events like ramayana, Mahabharata are repeated or
event of me posting here is also an repetition from the previous Chaturyuga.

If the Chaturyuga is destroyed at the end of cycle, how come the naga lok is not destroyed, since it has Lord Rama's rings from previous treta yugas, which are indeed of previous Chaturyuga.

Comment: AFAIK there is no scriptural evidence that suggests that every event will be repeated in every cycle. That is just a theory.

Comment: Look at the answers here http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2802/do-the-same-avatars-repeat-in-each-chaturyug

Comment: Good question I myself wonder why the events have to be repeated. Why do the same demons and avatars appear again and again.